# Rs485-TTL-Arduino data receive

Tags: arduino

I want read data from rs485 port to arduino using Rs232-TTL converter but I am not getting any data in arduino serial monitor.  Please help me.

Comment: Apparently `RS485` doesn't equal to `RS232`...

Comment: I have a rs485-rs232 converter, from rs232 output I connected to ttl

Answer (score 4):

Rs 485 uses differential signaling, Rs-232 dosn't, I'm not sure how you hooked it up, but I can't think of a way that would work, they are electrically incompatible.